# He pretend him or pretend to him?

Tags: prepositions

If I want to say that a person A went to people and said that he is person B... (he uses his name, as well as other his unique) what's the way to refer to it?

> He pretends him

or

> He pretends **to** him.

The preposition 'to' is idiomatic in this context?

Answer (score 1):

'He pretends to be him'.  If you want a single verb, you can say 'He impersonates him'

Comment: Reason: _pretend_ is an intransitive verb; it does not take a direct object.